# Screenshot is not loaded in my Jenkins Result Page

Tags: selenium, firefox, jenkins

My Testcase execution result will be displayed in the form of .html.

1. When I double click and open the .html file, the testcases results
   along with the Pass or Fail screenshot will be displayed.
2. I am executing the selenium testcases in Mozilla Firefox browser
3. When I open the .html file from my local machine, the images for
   every are loaded without any errors.

When I try to open the same .html file from any other system, images are not loaded.

Can somebody help me out in this issue?

Comment: htmlReport = new ExtentReports((rptPath + File.separator + "HTML Report.html"),true);

rptPath = "E:" + File.separator + Automation Results + File.separator
       + HTML Report + File.separator
       + resultFolderName;

When i open the .html file from my local machine, the images for every are loaded without any errors.

When i try to open the same .html file from any other system, images are not loaded.

Can somebody help me out in this issue.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the information in your comment. Make sure you read the stackoverflow's help pages before you post a question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not able to view HTML properties of your HTML reports. This is working fine as per default Jenkins behavior.

Run below in Script Console (available in Manage Jenkins) to view HTML and CSS properties:

System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")

Comment: Do i need to run this above line of code everytime before i start my test run??

Comment: you can try java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="sandbox; default-src 'self';" -jar jenkins.war

Comment: OR System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox; default-src 'self';") from within jenkins script console.